# Is else block mandatory in nested when statements in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kotlin code snippet that uses nested when statements. I noticed that the compiler requires an else block in the inner when statement, even though the outer when statement already covers all the cases for the enum class. Here's the code:

```kotlin
enum class Number {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
}

fun main(type: Number) {
    when (type) {
        Number.ONE, Number.TWO -> {
            when (type) {
                Number.ONE -> {}
                Number.TWO -> {}
                // Compiler requires else block here
                else -> {}
            }
        }
        Number.THREE -> {}
    }
}
```

Is the **`else`** block really necessary in this case? If so, why? Are there any articles or documentation that explain this behavior?

##### What did you try and what were you expecting?

I tried using nested **`when`** statements to handle different cases of the enum class **`Number`**. I was expecting that the inner **`when`** statement wouldn't require an **`else`** block since the outer **`when`** statement already covers all the possible enum values. However, the compiler insists on having an **`else`** block in the inner **`when`** statement.

Comment: I can show you the relevant sections of the language spec, but is there a reason you are writing nested `when` statement? Why not just "flatten" it?

Comment: @Sweeper
Thank you for your response, Sweeper. The reason I'm using nested when statements is to perform some common operations for Number.ONE and Number.TWO before branching into their specific behaviors. I understand that flattening could be an option, but I'm curious to know why the else block is required in this specific nested scenario according to the language spec.

Comment: @Slaw It is a reasonable expectation. The inner `when` is inside `Number.ONE, Number.TWO -> { ... }`, so `type` can only be `ONE` and `TWO` case. It is also reasonable to believe that a non-exhaustive `when` *can* be used as a statement.

Comment: @Slaw
Thank you for your question, Slaw. My initial thought was that since the outer when statement already covers all the possible values of the enum Number, and we are already within the conditions of ONE or TWO, the inner when statement might not require an else block for exhaustiveness. However, I'm open to understanding why this is not the case according to the language spec.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks. Ended up realizing the same thing as the second part of your comment (non-exhaustive when _statements_ make sense). As for the inner `when` being inside `Number.ONE, Number.TWO ->` part, I think that might be asking too much of the compiler (or maybe that's just the Java in me talking).

Comment: @Sweeper
Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, Sweeper. Your insights are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a `when` expression is exhaustive or not is determined by its branches, and the bound value *only*.

See the [spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#exhaustive-when-expressions):

> A `when` expression is called exhaustive if at least one of the
> following is true:
>
> - It has an `else` entry;
> - It has a bound value and at least one of the following is true:
>
>   - ...
>   - The bound expression is of an `enum class` type and all its enumerated values are checked for equality using constant expression;
>   - ...

The code before and after the `when` does not matter

If we just consider the inner `when` without the `else` entry:

```
when (type) {
    Number.ONE -> {}
    Number.TWO -> {}
}
```

It is clearly not exhaustive. `type` is of type `Number`, and the entries does not cover all 3 cases of `Number`.

According to the spec, the inner `when` should be valid, because non-exhaustive `when`s can be used as statements.

> The type of the resulting when expression is the least upper bound of the types of all its entries. If when expression is not exhaustive, it has type `kotlin.Unit` and may be used only as a statement.

However, according to [KT-47709](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47709/Make-when-statements-with-enum-sealed-and-Boolean-subjects-exhaustive-by-default), `when` statements with an enum as its bound value *must* be exhaustive. The [documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) also agrees. I can't find where this is stated in the spec though. It might not be up to date.

> #### Proposed Changes
>
> Make non-exhaustive when statements with enum, sealed, and Boolean
> subjects (and the nullable versions of the corresponding types) a
> compilation ERROR consistently with when expressions. This consistent
> treatment will remove the need for developers to figure out whether
> the corresponding when-with-subject in the source code is a statement
> or an expression in order to see if exhaustiveness is checked by a
> compiler or not. It will always be checked.

See the ticket for a more detailed explanation of the rationale.

---

That said, there is also [a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46501/Smartcast-when-subject-in-nested-exhaustive-when-expression) proposing the feature you want.

For now, you can use `when` *without* a bound value if you really hate the empty `else` bock, though this will produce some warnings (incorrectly) telling you to change it to a `when` with bound values:

```
when {
    type == Number.ONE -> {}
    type == Number.TWO -> {}
}
```

Comment: Not the specification, but this [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) claims the OP's case requires an `else` branch, regardless of the `when` being an expression or a statement.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the link. It seems like the spec is not up to date.

Comment: @Sweeper Slaw
Thank you, Slaw and Sweeper, for your thorough explanations and for directing me to the relevant spec and ticket, KT-47709. Your insights have clarified why the else block is necessary in my specific nested when scenario. I'm also intrigued by the proposed changes and the existence of a ticket proposing the feature I'm interested in. I appreciate your time, effort, and patience in helping me understand this complex issue, especially considering my limited English skills.